# How to create Nested Accordion in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

2015

-- Jan

-- Feb

```
  -- Link 1

  -- Link 2
```

2014

-- Jan

-- Feb

```
  -- Link 1

  -- Link 2
```

I want same views accordion feature on this listing with expand or collapse feature .

First user select year then month then we show the node title according to month & year .

I have already try views accordion module it shows accordion only for first and second level.